# Stable computation of $\log\sum x_i$ from $\log x_i$, with many terms

Tags: algorithms, error-estimation

[Kahan's summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) is a method to compute sums:

$$\sum x_i$$

with many terms, without significant error.

I want to do this with very large numbers, and instead of the numbers themselves, I am given their logarithms, $\log x_i$ ($x_i > 0$), and instead of the sum, I want to compute the logarithm of the sum,

$$\log \sum x_i$$

Is there a variation of Kahan's summation for this case?

Comment: Check out this [related post](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/how-to-add-large-exponential-terms-reliably-without-overflow-errors). Also worth looking up `logsumexp`.

Comment: @GoHokies I think the logexpsum trick doesn't work well if you have a single very large term and many very small terms.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/24624/988